# compile code in apue manually but get error

Tags: linux, compilation

I have typed the code of apue's appendixB by my own. but when I do the first test, I get an error.

```
`(master)⚡ [1] % clang -o myls myls.c apue.c`                               `~/Code/c/apue`
/tmp/apue-cf5ea0.o: In function `log_open':

apue.c:(.text+0xb95): undefined reference to `log_to_stderr'

/tmp/apue-cf5ea0.o: In function `log_doit':

apue.c:(.text+0xe28): undefined reference to `log_to_stderr'

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-clang-3.5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is my part of my apue.c :

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include "apue.h"

static void log_doit(int, int, int, const char *, va_list ap);

extern int log_to_stderr;

void log_open(const char *ident, int option, int facility) {
  if (log_to_stderr == 0)
    openlog(ident, option, facility);
}
static void log_doit(int errnoflag, int error, int priority, const char *fmt,
                     va_list ap) {
  char buf[MAXLINE];

  vsnprintf(buf, MAXLINE-1, fmt, ap);
  if (errnoflag)
    snprintf(buf+strlen(buf), MAXLINE-strlen(buf)-1, ": %s",
             strerror(error));
  strcat(buf, "\n");
  if (log_to_stderr) {
    fflush(stdout);
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fflush(stderr);
  } else {
    syslog(priority, "%s", buf);
  }
}
```

I have typed `extern int log_to_stderr` , but why I also get the error?
I'm using linux-gentoo.

Comment: Do you declare `int log_to_stderr;` in `myls.c`?

Comment: thanks, this is my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `extern` to declare an element without defining it (in case of a variable to declare a variable without initializing it), the memory for the declared element is not allocated, and this leads to the compilation error.

Make sure yo have declared `log_to_stderr` in `myls.c`:

```c
int log_to_stderr;
```